# 3d Reconstruction from live video feed

Tags: java, video, 3d, 3d-reconstruction

i was wondering if anyone has knowledge on the recontruction of 3D objects from live video feed. Does any have any java based examples or papers JAVA based that i could be linked to as i have read up on algorithm's used to produce such 3d objects. If possible i would like to construct something such as the program demostrated in the link provided below.
Currently my program logs live video feed.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brkHE517vpo&feature=related

Comment: That's an incredibly hard problem. Very likely, the method in the video does not work that great in general.

Comment: If you control the video camera, then you could use a kinect.

Comment: Though the programs ive seen online seem to have been in c++ so im sure this si achievable, in a controlled envoirment, with Java.

Answer (score 3):

3D reconstruction of an object from a single point of view is not really possible.  You have two basic alternatives: a) To have a stereo camera system capturing the object, b) To have only one camera, but rotating the object (so you will have different points of view of the object), like the one in the video.  This is a basic concept related with [epipolar geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipolar_geometry).

There are other alternatives, but more intrusive.  Some time ago I've been working on a 3D scanner based on a single camera and a laser beam.

[image]

For this, I used [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencv/) which is C++ code, but now I think there are ports for Java.  Have in mind that 3D reconstruction is not an easy task, and the resulting app. will have to be largely parametrized to achieve good results.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solved problem - certain techniques can do it to a certain degree under the right conditions. For example, the linked video shows a fairly simple flat-faced object being analysed while moving slowly under relatively even lighting conditions.

The effectiveness of such techniques can also be considerably improved if you can get a second (stereo vision) video feed.

But you are unlikely to get it to work for general video feeds. Problem such as uneven lighting, objects moving in front of the camera, fast motion, focus issues etc. make the problem extremely hard to solve. The best you can probably hope for is a partial reconstruction which can then be reviewed and manually edited to correct the inevitable mistakes.

[JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) and related projects are probably the best resource if you want to explore further. But don't get your hopes too high for a magic out-of-the-box solution!

Comment: The envoirment would be set up based on needs, you would only be scanning one object at a time, as that is what i am trying to achieve at the moment.